# Стоит ли перегружать асинхронные методы с CancellationToken?

Tags: c#, асинхронность, task

#### Введение

Я знаю, что раньше в C# было принято все асинхронные методы, что возвращают `Task`, перегружать с токеном отмены. Приведу для примера класс `TcpClient`:

```
public Task ConnectAsync(string host, int port);
public ValueTask ConnectAsync(string host, int port, CancellationToken cancellationToken);
```

Но в .NET 6.0 появился метод `WaitAsync`, который позволяет дождаться задачу с токеном отмены.

#### Вопрос

Актуален ли ещё паттерн перегрузки метода с `CancellationToken`, и если да, то чем это лучше `.WaitAsync(...)`?

Comment: `WaitAsync` - костыль, использовать его имеет смысл только в крайне редких случаях. И используется он только для того, чтобы соскочить с `await` **не отменяя задачу**, больше не для чего.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Принципиальная проблема метода `Task.WaitAsync` - в том, что он отменяет ожидание, но не отменяет задачу. Ваша задача всё равно выполнится до конца, просто вы не обязательно этого момента дождётесь.

Для экономии ресурсов надо передавать токен отмены так глубоко, как только можно, и не надеяться на костыли вроде WaitAsync.

Кстати, перегрузка всё же необязательная, но по другой причине - в свежем коде всегда можно использовать параметры по умолчанию:

```cs
public ValueTask ConnectAsync(string host, int port, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default) {
  // …
}
```